# How make table fit to iframe?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have table width `500px` and iframe fixed size of `200px`.

I need to make table fit to `iframe` using CSS or Bootstrap.

Any idea how can I make it?

Comment: Can you share some Code? Where is the Table?

Comment: Yes, some code would help. If the table is inside the document loaded within the iframe, setting the table width to be fluid (e.g. 100%) would make it fit inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I would use inline CSS on the table and just compress it into the iframe. You didn't provide any code, but it would look something like this:

```
<table style = "width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      <iframe> <!-- insert content here --> </iframe>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you perhaps switch places of table and iframe tags? The current code is not valid.

Comment: Yes. Good catch. Thanks you @IgorJerosimić

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!----- if iframe is inside----------------->
<table style = "width: 500px; height: 500px;">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
          <iframe> <!-- insert content here --> </iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
</table>



<!-- if table is inside --> 

<iframe style = "width: 200px; height: 200px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <table> </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</iframe>
```